# Objects added to array are overriding each other even when new array is created

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, push, javascript-objects

I have multiple members and multiple classes. I am trying to iterate over each class and search for the convenient data of all members depending on each class; In other words same members are repeated in each class but each time with new values; Now after calculating values I am logging members and values are correct as below:

[image: Members Logged]

here members are logged and InHosp values are correct.
But when I add them to the array it, it seems like members are repeated for each class with same values as you can see here:

[image: Array_Logged]

```
var Classes = [];


 angular.forEach(MembersAndClasses.Classes, function (value, key) {
     if (value.isChecked == true) {

        var objClass = new Object();
        objClass.ClassName = value.className;

        var arrMembers = new Array(); 
        //var principal = new Object();

        var principal = {};
        principal = MembersAndClasses.prinicipal;
        FillInOutHosp(principal, objClass.ClassName);                        
        arrMembers[0] = principal;
        //console.log(member);
        var counter = 1;

        angular.forEach(MembersAndClasses.FamilyMembers, function (value, key) {
            //var member = new Object();
            var member = {};
            member = value;
            FillInOutHosp(member, objClass.ClassName);        
            //console.log(member);
            arrMembers[counter] = member;
            counter = counter + 1;
            // console.log(arrMembers);
        });

            objClass.Members = arrMembers;
            Classes.push(objClass);
      }
   $scope.Classes = Classes;
 });
```

Why this is happening? each time (in angular.forEach) I am creating a new Array 
`var arrMembers = new Array();` then I am adding it to my objClass. So what could be the problem here?

Comment: `member = value;` is most likely the culprit. That does not copy the properties of `value` into the `member` object, but rather sets both variables to point to the *same* object!

Comment: And why logging member is returning correct data? And you mean by this to make member.X = value.X?

Comment: (to copy the variable, use `... = angular.copy(value)`)

Comment: Perfect, thank you both

Comment: @H.Al Because at the time of logging, the object is shown with the current value. I'm guessing `FillInOutHosp` will overwrite the values then on each iteration